# Visual Studio 2015 hangs while typing or moving between torn-off-editors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

As I type in a C# file while using Visual Studio 2015, it will intermittently hang for up to 30 seconds at a time.  This happens randomly and without any clear cause (no high CPU, or not after clicking a button).

When multiple editors have been torn off, clicking between windows also takes a long time.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?  Solving a specific and reproducible issue with a common tool used by programmers seems to be pretty on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a total whim, I presumed that the problem might be related to DDE / `SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, …)`.  A quick test program confirmed that a message sent to `HWND_BROADCAST` will hang the caller.

To figure out what window was the culprit, I wrote the test program below - which in my case pointed the finger at `OfficeC2RClient`.  Killing the `OfficeC2RClient` process resolved the issue.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SendMessageTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly IntPtr
            HWND_BROADCAST = (IntPtr)65535;
        private const int
            WM_NULL = 0;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, int fuFlags, int uTimeout, out IntPtr result);

        protected delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        protected static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder strText, int maxCount);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        protected static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        protected static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc enumProc, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        protected static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int processId);

        protected static bool EnumTheWindows(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            int size = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
            if (size++ > 0 && IsWindowVisible(hWnd))
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(size);
                GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, size);
                Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            }
            return true;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LoopSendMessage();
        }

        private static void BroadcastMessage()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var stp = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_NULL, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
                stp.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Duration = {0}", stp.Elapsed);

                if (stp.ElapsedMilliseconds > 250)
                {
                    Debugger.Break();
                }

                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }

        private static void LoopSendMessage()
        {
            if (EnumWindows(LoopSendMessage_Call, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Completed");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static bool LoopSendMessage_Call(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            IntPtr _unused;
            var stp = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            if (SendMessageTimeout(hWnd, WM_NULL, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 1, 5000, out _unused) == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                if (stp.ElapsedMilliseconds > 5)
                {
                    if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() == 1460)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"HWND {hWnd.ToString("x8")} timed out after {stp.ElapsedMilliseconds:n0}ms");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"HWND {hWnd.ToString("x8")} failed after {stp.ElapsedMilliseconds:n0}ms");
                    }

                    int pid;
                    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out pid);
                    var proc = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
                    Console.WriteLine($"    {proc.Id} {proc.ProcessName}");
                }
            }
            else if (stp.ElapsedMilliseconds > 250)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"HWND {hWnd.ToString("x8")} took {stp.ElapsedMilliseconds:n0}ms");
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```